# can't see some cs files while Getting Latest Version from TFS

Tags: c#

I'm using TFS as source Control, I try to get Latest Version, but some .cs files are missing in visual studio, when I open Folder where the project is these files are there but can't see in solution explorer whats the problem?

Comment: Are they added to the project?

Comment: when I open from source Control Explorer they are in their place doesn't mean that they are added?

Comment: No, it does not necessarily mean that. Check the solution explorer, are they in there? If not then you need to add them to the project.

Comment: how can I do that no they are not in solution explorer

Comment: This has nothing to do with TFS. The project files explicitly lists all the files that are considered part of the project. There can be more files on disk.

Comment: go to source control explorer and explictly get latest version of those files

Comment: Maybe the project file was not properly commited. Try to get the last version from the tfs source explorer.

Comment: @Ehsan Sajjad I tried that but it still gets all files but some are missing (they exist in File System but not in solution Explorer)

Comment: i am saying get specific .cs files that are not coming via solution or project

Comment: it says that the files are up to date

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you've run in to a merge issue, the files themselves can be in source and retrieved without actually being refrenced in the proj file.

There is a button on the top of your solution explorer, to the right of the minimize all, it looks like one document behind another. If you click this it will show all the files in the directory. You can then just right-click and Add on each file that you want